# Problem structuring database for an assessment rubric app

Tags: mysql, database-design

**Hello everyone**, I'm really troubled about how to design a database and I could use some help. I've done my research and found nothing about it.

I'm trying to build a simple app for my class that creates academic assessment rubrics so they are available to use them on my students and finally get grades.

I thought of using mysql for my database. The student part is done. But I can not think of a way to make the rubrics thing work.

I need to be able to create rubrics and inside that rubric create criterias, sub-criterias, sub-sub-criterias, levels and points. Here's and example of a rubric.

[image]

Could anyone give me some suggestion about how to model this database or any idea about it? Is a relational database a good approach for this problem? I'm kinda burnt with this and would appreciate
any recommendation.

Sorry for my English, not my native.
*Regards*.

Comment: It looks like for each student (id), there is an assessment (emergent -> excellent) based on each row in the rubrics above. Your english is very good, you don't need to apologise for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. The image was just an example of what a "rubric" was, if someone didn't knew and needed the context to work on my question. My problem is that I can't think on how to design a database to keep this rubrics and use them on students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll have students with an primary id `student_id`. Assume courses have a primary id `course_id`.

So each course will have its own assessment as per the first column in the rubric.

```
 create table courses_info (
   course_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment varchar(80) not null,
   primary key (course_id, assessment_id)
 )
```

Student assessments take `student_id`, `course_id`, `assessment_id` and store an `assessment_result` (assumed to be uniform over the entire institution):

```
 create table student_assessment (
   course_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment_id int unsigned not null,
   student_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment_result enum('Emergent',..., 'Excellent'),
   primary key (course_id, assessment_id, student_id)
 )
```

The rubric is the mapping between an `assessment_id` for each `course_id` with the `learning_outcome` being the element in the lookup table:

```
 create table rubric (
   course_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment_id int unsigned not null,
   assessment_result enum('Emergent',..., 'Excellent'),
   learning_outcomes text,
   primary key (course_id, assessment_id, assessment_result)
 )
```

To get the results you query and JOIN on the required columns:

Comment: So **learning_outcomes** would result in one of the parts of the rubric that says "has difficulty understanding and comprehending course materials"? (text next to Reads Actively) @danblack.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: you are the man. I really appreciate your answer, I understood it. I have to study more about database though. With this knowledge I can continue with my development, maybe I'll have more inquiries later.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct/useful. Its a pleasure to get such a well formed question on a first SO post. Best wishes with further development. More inquiries will probably be new questions. And never apologise for your written English, its good, and I generally think apologising for something you aren't good at in a help forum detracts from a realization that we are all just on different levels, and we shouldn't feel ashamed because of that.

Comment: I'll take it in consideration, thanks again Dan.